# HTML5 resume semantics

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I am working on my resume and want to use HTML5 semantics. 
What is the best semantic way to list my work experience? The information for each work experience contains the date, the company, the job title and a description.

I have two options in mind:

```
<h2>Experience</h2>
<ul>
  <dl>
    <dt><h3>JobTitle</h3> <span>Company + timeperiod</span></dt>
    <dd>description</dd>
   </dl>
</ul>
```

Or is it semantically more correct to consider each experience as an article as follows?

```
<h2>Experience</h2>
  <article>
    <h3>Jobtitle</h3> 
    <p>description</p>
    <footer>Company + timeperiod</footer>
  </article>
```

I would love to hear your thoughts on this one!

Comment: I know it's slightly different to what you're asking, but you should also check out the [hresume microformat](http://microformats.org/wiki/hresume)

Answer (score 8):

I would stick to nested <del>definition</del> description lists, as the `<article>` "[represents a component […] that consists of a self-contained composition […] that is **intended to be independently distributable or reusable**, e.g. in syndication](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-article-element)".

You are also doubling some things, like nesting the `<dl>` into an `<ul>` or having an heading (`<h3>`) inside of a `<dt>`-element.

```
<section>
    <h2>Experience</h2>
    <dl>
        <dt>THE JOB TITLE</dt>
        <dd>
            <dl>
                <dt>Company:</dt><dd>THE COMPANY</dd>
                <dt>Period:</dt><dd>
                    <time class="dtstart" datetime="2007-02-01">Feb 2007</time> -
                    <time class="dtend" datetime="2009-09-30">Sep 2009</time>,
                </dd>
                <dt>Description:</dt><dd>
                    DESCRIPTION
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </dd>
        <!-- more jobs here as dt-dd-pairs -->
    </dl>
</section>
```

[whatwg.org: the-time-element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element)

Comment: +1, this is the way to go. **Stop using `<article>`s everywhere.** Btw, @feeela, I'm not entirely sure whether `<time>` is relevant here.

Comment: I do not think Definition lists (DL) is the way to go either, your not defining a term

Comment: @Daveo …which isn't the requirement as of HTML 4.01: "[Definition lists vary only slightly from other types of lists in that list items consist of two parts: a **term** and a **description**.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.3)" And, as of HTML5 `dl` means [description list](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/dl.html#dl), not definition list. See also: http://html5doctor.com/the-dl-element/

Comment: What if the time interval was open-ended? That is, if the described position was your current position?

Answer (score 6):

I am doing this using `details`/`summary`, as well as other semantic tags like `section` and `header`.

```
<main>
  <header>
    <h1>Chunliang Lyu</h1>
    <a href="https://chunlianglyu.com/">chunlianglyu.com</a>
    <a href="https://github.com/cllu">github.com/cllu</a>
  </header>
  <section class="education">
    <h2>Education</h2>
    <details>
      <summary>The Chinese University of Hong Kong, <time>2011 - 2016</time></summary>
      Research Area: Entity Retrieval, Natural Language Processing, Knowledge Graph.
    </details>
  </section>
</main>
```

One advantage of `details` is that on supported browsers like Chrome, you can click the `summary` element to toggle display of the corresponding `details` element.

I have made a small app to convert Markdown text to HTML with above structure, also enabling semantic markup with schema.org. Check my project at https://github.com/cllu/Semantic-Resume, and the app at https://semantic-resume.chunlianglyu.com/.

Answer (score -1):

I would do it like so:

```
  <section>
     <h2>Experience</h2>
     <article>
         <h3>Jobtitle</h3> 
         <p>description</p>
         <footer>Company + timeperiod</footer>
     </article>
  </section>
```

Notice I also added the section tag. See http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/08/16/html5-and-the-document-outlining-algorithm/

Comment: Thx, seems there is a consensus going on...

I am using the section elements already for each type of content, like experience,personal info, skills,

Comment: @Katablosh - no problem, if you like an answer don't forget to up vote or mark it as correct ;)

Comment: As the information about the company and period is more important then the description itself (IMHO), I would put it into an `<header>` instead of a `<footer>`. (…if really using an article)

Comment: @feeela I was just keep in the original structure of the OP question as his question was not about footer or header. But <article> or <dl> Either way the in a CV description is more important then the company IMHO